Preview Crash with concatenated String
This is a simple SwiftUI macOS project where Preview crashes with a concatenated String within a Button function:
1 Here's a working project; preview works, compiles and runs
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var someString = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("test") {
            let s = "5\n+6\n--------\n=11"
            someString = s
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

2 the exact same project, with the "s" var set to a concatenated string; Project builds and runs but Preview crashes
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var someString = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("test") {
            let s = "5" + "\n" + "+6" + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + "=11"
            someString = s
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

The concern is not running the project but why Preview crashes when setting "s" - how does one use a concatenated string and have preview not crash?
The Preview Crash log shows

struct
$s55SwiftUI_macOS_Generic_PreviewReplacement_ContentView_133_4310061832465E826F14ECFDA24C0143Ll0F0fMf_15PreviewRegistryfMu_:
DeveloperToolsSupport.PreviewRegistry {
static var fileID: String {
"SwiftUI_macOS_Generic_PreviewReplacement_ContentView_1/ContentView.1.preview-thunk.swift"
}
static var line: Int {
24
}
static var column: Int {
1
}
    static func makePreview() throws -> DeveloperToolsSupport.Preview {
        DeveloperToolsSupport.Preview {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}



Strange behaviour. Probably another bug. Works if you declare the let s = ... in the View outside the Button. Note that Previews are not full simulators. Also works on a real mac.
